# Detect swipe over area in Android

Tags: android, andengine

In my game app that uses AndEngine, I'm trying to detect a swipe motion over a button Sprite to enlarge the button when the finger is over the button Sprite, and set scale back to 1.0f when the finger swipes off the Sprite. Meaning:

- finger down outside button area
- swipe over button (and button is sized up) but keep finger down
- continue swipe off button and button goes back to orginal scale.

I've tried following:

```
myButton = new Sprite(posX, posY, resourcesManager.rightButtonRegion, vbom) {


        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pAreaTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            switch (pAreaTouchEvent.getAction()) {
            case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                this.setScale(1.25f);
                break;

            case TouchEvent.ACTION_UP:
                this.setScale(1.0f);
                break;

            case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                this.setScale(1.0f);
                break;

            case TouchEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
                this.setScale(1.0f);
                break;

            }
            return true;
        }
    };
```

But if I start the swipe outside of the button and move my finger over the button the button is not scaled up in size. Appreciate any pointers to how to achieve this effect. If there is an non-Andengine solution using SurfaceView I'd appreciate any perspective on that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only set scale on `TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN`.  When you slide into your touch region, it does not register an `ACTION_DOWN` because you didn't press down in your region, you just moved into it.  Perhaps you could put a check into your `case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:` that scales up the first time you move into that region, if your touch sequence did not being with `ACTION_DOWN`.

If that doesn't work, you can use things like `onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent)` that deliver other types of motion event information.